# Сохранение директории со всем содержимым в папке с известным названием - Java

Tags: java, файлы

Есть диалоговые окна FileChooser - showOpenDialog для выбора директории и showSaveDialog для сохранения.

Нужно иметь возможность сохранять эту директорию со всем содержимым в любом    месте компютера именно через панель FileChooser. При этом должна    создаваться автоматически папка с определенным названием и в нее    помещена директория

буду благодарен только за ответ с    копированием - желательно пример кода.

код ниже (export - кнопка)

```
 export.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

     fileChooser = new JFileChooser("c:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\43\\");

     //fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("c:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\43\\"));
     fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Zapisz pliki");
     fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

     fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
         
     if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(DCMUploadFrame.this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
         System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): "
                            +  fileChooser.getCurrentDirectory());
         System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : "
                            +  fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
     } else {
         System.out.println("No Selection ");
     }

     if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(DCMUploadFrame.this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
         File fileToSave = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

         File source = fileToSave;
         File dest = new File("с:\\Users\\User\\Documents");
         try {
             FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, dest);
         } catch (IOException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Вам нужно установить флаг чузера в `JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY` - что вам даст возможность выбирать только каталоги
2. При срабатывании выбора юзера в `showOpenDialog` надо запускать `showSaveDialog()` где выбираем таргет каталог
3. При срабатывании выбора юзера в `showSaveDialog` - копируем.

> буду благодарен только за ответ с копированием - желательно пример кода.

здесь это так не работает - придется попотеть самому.